# Record the latest value for more than 3 column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a function in excel that will only take the latest value from four different column (Day 1 until 4 column). Until day 3 it record correctly but for day four the nothing happen. The total still recorded the latest day 3 value even though day have a new value. This is my funtion

```
=IF(AND(E3=I3,I3=M3,M3=Q3),Q3,
IF(Q3="Passed",Q3,
IF(M3="Passed",M3,
IF(I3="Passed",I3,
IF(E3="Passed",E3,
IF(Q3="Failed",Q3,
IF(M3="Failed",M3,
IF(I3="Failed",I3,
IF(E3="Failed",E3,
IF(Q3="No Run",Q3,
IF(M3="No Run",M3,
IF(I3="No Run",I3,
IF(E3="No Run",E3,"N/A")))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula seems to work OK for me, but it can be simplified to:

```
=IF(OR(E3="Passed",I3="Passed",M3="Passed",Q3="Passed"),"Passed",
 IF(OR(E3="Failed",I3="Failed",M3="Failed",Q3="Failed"),"Failed",
 IF(OR(E3="No Run",I3="No Run",M3="No Run",Q3="No Run"),"No Run",
 "N/A")))
```

(The only problem with the simplification is that it will return `"N/A"` instead of `0` if all cells are empty.  If that is an issue, you can add your extra `IF(AND(E3=I3,I3=M3,M3=Q3),Q3` condition to the front of it again.)

---

If your issue is that you want to take the value of Q3 if it is non-blank, else take the value of M3 if it is non-blank, else take the value of I3 if it is non-blank, else take the value of E3 if it is non-blank, else use "N/A", then your formula should be

```
=IF(Q3<>"",Q3,IF(M3<>"",M3,IF(I3<>"",I3,IF(E3<>"",E3,"N/A"))))
```